If we can say "roomy jackets", can we say "a roomy shirt"?
collinsdictionary.com:

If you describe a piece of clothing as roomy, you mean that you like it because it is large and fits loosely:
roomy jackets

On hinative.com two American English speakers said "a roomy shirt" is unnatural.
Why is "a roomy shirt" unnatural whereas "roomy jackets" is natural?

Also I'm curious about whether we can also use "spacious" with clothes or not. E.g.:
Is "spacious jackets" natural?

roomy is opposed to tight for clothing. No not spacious.

This might be more of a fashion question than a language question (not a fashion expert by any means, but) I suspect it might be that a "well fitting" shirt is neither too loose or too tight. I.e my implication is that shirts have a "higher standard" for  accurate fit than Jackets - again not a fashion expert.

In my experience, this use of "roomy" is not very common in modern AmE, though I would certainly understand it.  That may be where commentators who find it unnatural are coming from.  But I don't think it is any more (or less) unnatural for shirts than it is for jackets.

If you told me you preferred roomy shirts I would know exactly what you meant.

I actually edited away the link to the ultra-low-quality web site.  Having links to ultra-low-quality web sites, on a high quality web site like this one, is an extremely bad idea.

@Loviii regarding spacious, the thing is it makes sense and sounds natural (in the sense that anything novel may indeed sound natural and novel), but it is not common.  Questions about "naturalness" among native speakers is tricky business. If I said "My God, this bathrobe is all-encompassing!" 100% of native speakers would find me literate, witty, a Real Experienced Speaker, a Person Who's Phrases Roll Off The Tongue, etc, but it is not a common thing to say.

@Fattie The sentence "On hinative.com two American English speakers said "a roomy shirt" is unnatural" is explanatory, i.e. it shows the reason why I'm asking the following question: "Why is "a roomy shirt" unnatural whereas "roomy jackets" is natural?". If we remove this explanatory sentence, somebody is sure to ask me: "Why do you think "a roomy shirt" is unnatural?".

Cheers @Lovii .  (i) your question is great  (ii) nobody would challenge you on your great question about 'roomy'  (iii) if you look at 1000 questions on here, 900 are "is X natural?" - you absolutely don't have to give some "reference" for why you asked.  overwhelmingly (iv) garbage like the site mentioned (pls don't mention it again in comments) should never be mentioned on a site like this.  Anything like this that smacks of being spammy for garbage sites is deleted straight away.  This site and the companion site are extremely "high SEO" in google, gotta keep it that way!

@Fattie I understand what you're saying. But I think moderators wouldn't agree about it. If you're interested, you might talk with, for example, the moderator "gotube" who gave one of the answers to the original post. They could explain the rules and recommendations on ELL far better than me.

{ The social norms differ on the sundry SE sites an interesting one is, I'd say, for example mild swearing is or isn't tolerated differently on these sites.  Another one is the level fo comment discussion allowed, it varies on the sites! }

I can't stand "wikipedia" being used as a reference, but, am not going to win that one now  :/

roomy clothes is a well-attested collocation in both British and American English. Check Google Books for details.

I like a really roomy shirt. I hate feeling constricted.
Here's a pattern for a roomy shirt.

roomy shirt has been used for over 150 years.
There, it means "loose fitting".  room is often used in the context of clothing.  When being fitted for trousers, say, one could tell the tailor:

There's too much room in the seat.
They need more room in the seat.

"Spacious clothing", no, not as a collocation.

'Spacious' isn't natural, so I wouldn't use it unless I wanted to make a point about how very large something is: "That jacket my mother bought me, it's... spacious. Perhaps I'll grow into it in 30 years."

@user1908704  It would be a sardonic use of spacious, well "over-the-top". This jacket is so capacious it's spacious.

I would like to point out that while ‘roomy clothing’ (and other similar uses) is well attested, that does not mean it sounds natural in any arbitrary dialect. In at least some dialects, ‘roomy’ tends to have an association with rigid structures, which doesn’t quite fit naturally with most types of clothing.

@AustinHemmelgarn Which dialects in particular are you referring to?

@AustinHemmelgarn fair enough, but your comment, your caveat, applies to every utterance in English.

It's not unnatural as a rule, but it might be unnatural in context, and there may be a better word:  a "baggy shirt", an "oversize shirt", even "comfy shirt" might carry some of the same of the same sense.
For formal writing just use simple words like "large".

"Roomy" is generally a positive term: it's good because it's large. While "baggy" can be negative. So it depends on whether you want a larger item of clothing. A tight jacket made of heavy fabric will be hard to put on and will restrict your movement, so more space is better. In contrast, shirts are often worn cut close to the body, especially to fit under other layers of clothing and avoid getting sleeves etc caught up, and being made of softer, thin fabric shirts don't restrict movement as much. So it might make sense sometimes to praise a shirt as roomy, but not often.

I wouldn't use roomy of a shirt. Apart from anything else, because I'm from UK South, the vowel in my room is short (like book), but my vowel in roomy is long (like rheum, and who wants snotty mucusy clothing?), so I'm always a bit diffident about using it at all. I'd just use words like large, loose, generous,... for clothing, and spacious for more literal contexts (so my "roomy room" would be a "spacious room").

Your choice of adjective, I think,  depends not only on the general statement you are making (i.e. that the shirt is loose-fitting), but also on the subtler, more precise message you are trying to convey. “Roomy” has a positive connotation. You’re saying you are happy with the looseness of the shirt. “Baggy” usually has a negative connotation since you’re comparing the clothing article to a bag, which is generally cheap and lacks the refined structure of nice clothing. Other adjectives have their own subtle implications.

"Comfy" does not necessarily mean "roomy".  "Comfy" can simply be a result of soft material.  For example, a sweater or a flannel shirt can be "comfy" while not being "roomy".  Shoes and socks can be "comfy" when they are made of soft material, even when they are not "roomy".

Yeah, that's already mentioned in the answer, what would you have me change

To my Canadian ears, "roomy" only applies to things that can hold their shape, so a "roomy shirt" is incorrect.
Many jackets are stiff enough that if you put one on that's too large, it's essentially a container, and your arms or body can move relative to the jacket.
Shirts, on the other hand, tend to just hang off the body, and not create any room inside that you can move within. If you move your arms or body in a shirt, the shirt moves with you.
But not always. TimR found this "roomy shirt" which holds its shape because the corduroy fabric is so stiff.
So yes, it's possible, but not at all common.

"Mens large roomy shirts" are on sale at Simpson's in Toronto for only 89¢   -- hurry over while they last.  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Canadian_Mining_Journal/I8YgAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=roomy+shirt+in+Canada&pg=PT1&printsec=frontcover

I'm afraid I can't agree with this, sorry

@TimR Can you cite something from less than 100 years ago?

In the 1980s, our clothes were so roomy and held their shape, we didn't even need to exercise! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMF5aIs_4os

@gotube It's hard to find something that is specifically Canadian given my limited Google-fu.  But here's a contemporary attestation: https://www.wconcept.com/product/corduroy-roomy-shirt-3-colors/710754443.html

And there are plenty of attestations of shirts with lots of room

@TimR Nice find. That is a roomy shirt because the material is so stiff that it holds its shape. I wonder if that's what the OP intends? And maybe those 1907 shirts were also stiff. Either way, I've added this to my answer.

Not sure stiffness is the essential feature.  "One Size fits all but this is a roomy 'moo moo', can be off the shoulder or worn with a camisole or tank under."  https://www.etsy.com/listing/1312152714/made-by-mary-bee?dd_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

"It is delightful, as every woman knows, to doff a tight-fitting gown and step into a comfortable and roomy negligee, where you can feel perfectly at ease."  Boston College Newspapers. The Sacred Heart Review, Volume 31, Number 16, 16 April 1904 https://newspapers.bc.edu/?a=d&d=BOSTONSH19040416-01.1.15&  See the column with the header Ladies Dressing Sack on p.15

@TimR OK. It's attested. Doesn't mean it's natural, and to me it is not.
